# Getting paginated data from ajax call and putting the data on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination

At the moment, it gets the first page worth of data and then each subsequent page when the user scrolls down to the bottom of the page.

My JavaScript/jQuery level is fairly weak, however I have managed to cobble this together and would like to know how I can improve my code.

```js
 var page = 1;

 $(function() {
   getUsers(page);
   page++;
 });


 $(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
     getUsers(page);
     page++;
   }
 });

 function getUsers(page) {

   $.ajax({
     url: '/ajax/users?page=' + page
   }).done(function(data) {
     var users = data;
     var user;
     var url = "<?php echo url('profile/') ?>";

     if (page > users.last_page) {
       return true;
     } else {
       $.each(users.data, function(key, value) {
         var image;
         if (value.image[0]) {
           image = value.image[0].name;
         } else {
           if (value.profile.gender == 'male') {
             image = 'maleDefault.png';
           } else {
             image = 'femaleDefault.jpg';
           }
         }
         user = "<div class='col-xs-6 col-md-3'> <a href='" + url + "/" + value.username + "' class='thumbnail'><img src='http://localhost:8000/image/" + image + "'" +
           "class='img-rounded' alt='' width='196.372' height='159.368'></a></div>";
         $('.panel-body').append(user);
       });
     }
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

When you have an `if/else` statement inside an `else` statement and that is the only thing inside that statement, you should make the `else` statement into and `else if` instead.  So you would change this:

> ```
>      if (value.image[0]) {
>        image = value.image[0].name;
>      } else {
>        if (value.profile.gender == 'male') {
>          image = 'maleDefault.png';
>        } else {
>          image = 'femaleDefault.jpg';
>        }
>      }
> ```

to this

```
if (value.image[0]) {
   image = value.image[0].name;
} else if (value.profile.gender == 'male') {
     image = 'maleDefault.png';
} else {
     image = 'femaleDefault.jpg';
}
```

All that this does is remove a level of indentation to make the code easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

As @Malachi points out, your indentation is off, and you really ought to fix that (*Four spaces instead of two*)

---

You could replace the following with a nice little ternary statement, which follow the structure:

```
variable == variableToCompare ? doSomethingIfTrue() : doSomethingIfFalse();
```

> ```
>      if (value.image[0]) {
>        image = value.image[0].name;
>      } else {
>        if (value.profile.gender == 'male') {
>          image = 'maleDefault.png';
>        } else {
>          image = 'femaleDefault.jpg';
>        }
>      }
> ```

Which could become:

```
if (value.image[0]) {
    image = value.image[0].name;
} else {
    image = (value.profile.gender != 'male' ? 'fe' : '') + 'maleDefault.png';
}
```

Or even (*if you're daring*):

```
image = (value.image[0] ? value.image[0].name :
            (value.profile.gender != 'male' ? 'fe' : '') + 'maleDefault.png')
        );
```